# how to filter an array having values in another array?

Tags: typescript, angular8

I want to filter array not having the `user` as a name. In the end, I will get only `id of 2,3` from the array two by doing so. What is the efficient way? 
I tired to use `some and filter` but it says `some and filter is not a function`.

**First Array**

```
0: "user"
1: "dashboards"
```

**Second Array**

```
0: {id: "1", name: "admin", normalizedName: "admin", concurrencyStamp: null, selected: false}
1: {id: "2", name: "dashboard", normalizedName: "dashboard", concurrencyStamp: "", selected: false}
2: {id: "3", name: "user", normalizedName: "user", concurrencyStamp: "", selected: false}
```

**My first Try**

```
for (var i = 0; i < sroles.length; i++) {
    for (var j = 0; j < roles.length; j++) {
        if (roles[j] == sroles[i].name) {
            realRoles.push(sroles[i]);
        }
    }
}
```

**Second Try**

```
var roles = {...this.user.roles};
var sroles ={...this.selectedRoles} ;

sroles.filter(function(e){
    return roles.some(x=>x ==e.name);
})
```

**Second try error**

> filter or some is not a function.

**third try**

```
 Object.keys(sroles).filter(element =>Object.values(roles).some(x=>x == sroles[element]));
```

**Desired Output**

```
0: {id: "2", name: "dashboard", normalizedName: "dashboard", concurrencyStamp: "", selected: false}
1: {id: "3", name: "user", normalizedName: "user", concurrencyStamp: "", selected: false}
```

**My solution which is working**

```
Object.keys(sroles).forEach(function (key) {
            Object.keys(roles).forEach(function (key2) {
                if (roles[key2] == sroles[key].name) {
                    realRoles.push(sroles[key]);
                }
            });
        });
```

Comment: Can you post the code that you have so far?

Comment: @Baruch Thank you for your comment. I added my tries but it seems inefficient.

Comment: Please specify your input and desired output

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [Array.prototype.filter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) and [Array.prototype.includes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/includes):

```js
const arr1 = ["user", "dashboard"];

const arr2 = [{
    id: "1",
    name: "admin",
    normalizedName: "admin",
    concurrencyStamp: null,
    selected: false
  },
  {
    id: "2",
    name: "dashboard",
    normalizedName: "dashboard",
    concurrencyStamp: "",
    selected: false
  },
  {
    id: "3",
    name: "user",
    normalizedName: "user",
    concurrencyStamp: "",
    selected: false
  }
];

const filtered = arr2.filter(({name}) => arr1.includes(name));

console.log(filtered);
```